# Generate PDF with XSL-FO for Android

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

Is it possible to generate a PDF in an Android application using XSL-FO?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: @stwissel Yes, but I can't help you since I don't have the code anymore.

Comment: Just was curious. I render PDF on server. Can u remember what tools you used at the end?

Comment: I have created an issue on fop project regarding this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Apache FOP and see if the required dependencies are includes in Android's runtime. It might be rather slow. You could use iText or PDFBox to render PDF - or use a server and let Android just request a PDF creation.