# Does Apache FOP work on Android?

Tags: java, android, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We have an `Android` application that needs to generate `PDFs` from `XML` data making use of `XSL-FO` templates. To this end I have been looking at libraries to use in our Android app that can do the conversion of the `XML` to `PDF`. As the application needs to be able to work offline generation of the `PDF` via a server is *not* an option for us.

I have been considering using `Apache FOP` but have received conflicting information online about whether `Apache FOP` will work on `Android` or not. [This blog](http://stefan.fenz.at/creating-pdfs-on-android-an-evaluation/) for example states that `FOP` on `Android` is "inappropriate", but does not outline specifically what issues were encountered when attempting to use it. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393679/generate-pdf-with-xsl-fo-for-android) on the other hand seems to imply that it is theoretically possible to get `FOP` working on Android.

What I am looking for here is some clarity to what the actual situation is regarding using `Apache FOP` in an `Android` application. Has anyone tried it and can confirm whether it does or does not work? If it doesn't, could anyone give specific details about the missing dependencies or issues that would occur when trying to use it on `Android`?  I am needing to evaluate, if there are dependency issues, how serious these are and the amount of work it would take to overcome these issues.

Comment: I haven't ever tried to use it on Android, but I am going to guess that you will run into resource problems.  Fop does use a fair amount of memory (depending on your document).  Do you generate the XML as well?  If so, you may consider using a pdf generation library and just writing straight to pdf.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, I will be generating the XML as well, although that will not be very memory intensive.The reason that I need to use FOP is because the layout of the PDF is defined by the customer and saved using XSL-FO. I am trying to do the conversion of FOP to Android. If it runs into resource problems I will find out about it soon. :)

Comment: @BruceHill I am having same issue. did you got the solution?

Comment: No, sorry, Pratik. I tried but eventually gave up because of dependencies that I could not get working on Android.

Comment: I have created an issue on fop project regarding this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2915

Answer (score 1):

With Android, you can't just take a .jar from a Java library and use it in an Android application. 
Android uses the Dalvik JVM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) 
which is not 100% compatible with the full API from the Java SE API, and instead only supports a subset of the API. For this reason, many of the Java libraries you might be use to, like FOP, are not Android compatible as-is and 
require specialization before such libraries will function properly on an Android device.

Comment: Ok. I am aware of that, but what I was actually looking for with this question was specifics. Which dependencies are missing or which specific API calls are relied upon that are missing from Dalvik JVM. Has anyone tried to port it? That is the gist of my question.